# PythonでMacの、Library/Application Supportフォルダのパスを取得する方法

Tags: python, macos

Windowsでは、ユーザーの設定ファイルを保存する場合、%APPDATA%というパスに保存するようなのですが、そのパスをPythonを取得しようと思ったら以下のようにgetenvで取得できるようです。

```
import os
APPNAME = 'testFolder'
os.path.join(os.getenv('APPDATA'),APPNAME)
```

Macの場合では、Winの%APPDATA%にあたるユーザーの設定ファイル等の保存場所がLibrary/Application Supportフォルダにあたるらしいのですが、このパスを取得するにはどうするのが良いですか？

Macの場合でもgetenv等で取得できますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自分では試せていませんが書いておきます。
やはり macOS ではそういう環境変数は存在せず、通常 Swift で [FileManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager) クラスを呼び出して取得するようです。
本家SO: [Programatically get path to Application Support folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39719123).
公式ドキュメント: [macOS Library Directory Details](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/MacOSXDirectories/MacOSXDirectories.html)

Python で Foundation フレームワークの FileManager クラスを使うのは PyObjC とか [pyobjc-framework-Cocoa](https://pypi.org/project/pyobjc-framework-Cocoa/)を使うそうです。

フォルダパスを得たいだけなのにパッケージを新たにインストールするのはやりすぎな気もします…

Answer (score 0):

取得できません。
`getenv`は単に環境変数の値を取得するだけに過ぎず、Macでは`~/Library/Application Support`に対する環境変数は設定されていません。

WindowsでもMacでも稼働するプログラムを作成中なら、OSを判定して各OS毎のパスを設定するなどするしかないと思います。

なおOS判定は次のように実現できます。

```py
import platform

print(platform.system()) #=> 'Windows' or 'Darwin' or 'Linux'
```